# Binary Tree in vector C++

Tags: c++

Im currently working on a school project where i have to make a Binary Tree of integers(Avl specifically)and make a catalog where catalog node is an AvlTree.So I used vectors to make the catalog//vector catalog.
My code for the catalog is:

```
  class ClassInvertedIndex
{
    public:
        ClassInvertedIndex();
        void insertToCatalog(int ,int );
        void deleteFromCatalog(int,int);
        vector<AvlTree> catalog;
    protected:

    private:
};

void ClassInvertedIndex::insertToCatalog(int a,int b){
 AvlTree aa;
 if(catalog.size()==0){
catalog.push_back(aa);
catalog[0].insertNode(catalog[0].root,a);
catalog[0].insertNode(catalog[0].root,b);
  return;
 }
else {
    for(unsigned i=0;i<catalog.size();i++){
        if(catalog[i].root->data==a){
            catalog[i].insertNode(catalog[i].root,b);
            return;
        }
    }

}
catalog.push_back(aa);
catalog[catalog.size()-1].insertNode(catalog[catalog.size()-1].root,a);
catalog[catalog.size()-1].insertNode(catalog[catalog.size()-1].root,b);
return ;
}

void ClassInvertedIndex::deleteFromCatalog(int a,int b){
if(catalog.size()==0)
    return;
for(unsigned i=0;i<catalog.size();i++){
 if(catalog[i].root->data==a){
    catalog[i].deleteNode(catalog[i].root,b);
 }
}
}

So when i give as input
cc.insertToCatalog(8,9);
  cc.insertToCatalog(8,7);
an avltree is with root 8 and nodes 7 & 9 is stored(the balance functions are in
the avltree class).
but if i put 
cc.insertToCatalog(8,9);
  cc.insertToCatalog(8,7);
 cc.insertToCatalog(0,1)
```

which should create the first avl tree(8,9,7) and the second (0,1) the program stops working(but is compiled fine).I tried to find where the problem is and its in the insertToCatalog function in the last 3 lines( i guess dynamic problem).Could you suggest me how to fix it?

Comment: Use a debugger. Unless you come up with a [mcve], instead of isolated code fragments, it's unlikely that an answer is possible.

Comment: thank you very much.I did debug and foound out vector wasnt that easy to handle with pointer objects so i made a linked listed